# Poor performance getting 1 property of related object in entity framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, data-binding

I have the following property:

```
 Public ReadOnly Property AppointmentDate As Date?
    Get
        Dim _apt = _person.Appointments.OrderBy(Function(c) c.AppointmentDate).FirstOrDefault
        If IsNothing(_apt) Then Return Nothing
        Return _apt.AppointmentDate
    End Get
End Property
```

When i databind a large amount of records (around 1,000) the databind takes roughly 30-40 seconds.  If i remove this property, it takes 1-2 seconds for the entire databind.

I've tried changing it to this:

```
  Public ReadOnly Property AppointmentDate As Date?
    Get

        If _cxt.Appointments.Where(Function(p) p.LeadId = _person.Id).Count() = 0 Then Return Nothing
        Dim _apt = _person.Appointments.OrderBy(Function(c) c.AppointmentDate).FirstOrDefault
        Return _apt.AppointmentDate
    End Get
End Property
```

Thinking that by just performing a count would result in less overhead, but it is still just as slow.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you reading this property before you need it?  If you need it all the time for this entity, can you populate it when you first retrieve the data, rather than performing 1000 subqueries to get each one?

Comment: What if you try `ANY` first, then `MAX`. `Order by` should be last thing. `where` is also slower and not needed.

Comment: I need it every time.... Would eager loading improve performance? The other option I considered was, since i just need the most recent  value in there extend the model so the person object includes that property and then background task to update it. I still can't understand why 1000 queries takes just seconds; but when adding 1 subquery the time increases 100x

Comment: Is it possible to do a JOIN on the two tables prior to executing?